# Whats the availability like on the Stripe Payments API? Can I rely on it always being online for my Price Plan Prices?

Tags: api, server, stripe-payments

I am developing a stripe integration. I have a product and price table in my planned database. I'm wondering whether I should also store the price information of a plan in my own database just incase their API goes down and our server can't access it. Can I assume their server's always going to be up and fetch the price from their API, or should I duplicate this information in my own database

Comment: You can assume it will always be up.

Comment: 99.9% uptime https://status.stripe.com/

Comment: Don't forget uptime isn't the only issue. Latency and rate limits matter, too. Making a HTTP request to Stripe every time someone views your pricing page is bad for performance; consider at least *caching* the result.